# Webpack Configuration Error - where is the bug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I try to run "node index.js" and get the following error message:

ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.module.rules[0] should be one of these:
  ["..." | object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
  -> A rule.
  Details:

  - configuration.module.rules[0].loader should be a non-empty string.
    -> A loader request.

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './main.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: '/',
    filename: 'main-bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          prefix: 'font/',
          limit: '5000',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: '10000',
          mimetype: 'image/svg+xml',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Please help me find the error, I've read the documentation and just can't find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the html in a string to `res.end`. Since you have multiple lines of html, you can use [template-literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) (note the backticks `..`) to make it easier.

Using template-literals you can define embedded expressions using `${expression}` that will be concatenated into the resulting string. In your example this is used to set e.g. the hostname: `${os.hostname}`:

```
res.end(`<html><head><title>Operating System Info</title></head><body><h1>Operating System Info</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><th>TMP Dir</th><td>${os.tmpdir()}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Host Name</th><td>${os.hostname()}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>OS Type</th><td>${os.type()}</td></tr> 
        ${os.platform()}
        ${os.arch()} $os.release()}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Uptime</th><td>${os.uptime()} ${util.inspect(os.loadavg())}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>Memory</th><td>total: ${os.totalmem()} free: ${freemem()}</td></tr>
        <tr><th>CPU's</th><td><pre>${util.inspect(os.cpus())}</pre></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Network</th><td><pre>${util.inspect(os.networkInterfaces())}</pre></td>,/tr>
        </table>
        </body></html>`);
```

Comment: @Adam: why did you unaccept? If your question changed, please post a new one...

Comment: I got some downvotes on this question and got blocked from asking questions.  The user guide instructs to re-write the question to make it better for the community, so I wrote a new questions.  I really have no idea how to get out of blocked status!  I don't know what I'm doing!  Can you give some advice?

Comment: From my understanding, you should just improve the existing one, not rewrite it as an entire new question. Unfortunately there's really not much you can do, until your questions get upvoted, I'm afraid. Anyway, I've upvoted your question since in my opinion your it was ok in the first place.

Comment: I accepted your answer and upvoted it as well, Thanks I appreciate you upvoting mine!

Answer (score 0):

> `res.end(<html><head><title>Hello, world!</title></head><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1>`

The HTML you send back from here (and throughout your code) needs to be in a string so it can parse it and then send that HTML later on because you can't just put HTML anywhere in Javascript (and this isn't React for example).

```js
 // the right way to do it
 res.end("<html><head><title>Hello, world!</title></head><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1>")
```

Also enclose all other occurrences of html in your code within quotes so they become valid strings too.